# Remove or Hide field in PDF document using iTextSharp

Tags: pdf, itext, livecycle, xfa

Is there a way to remove or hide field in PDF document using iTextSharp library. It seems that iTextSharp can not do this for PDF templates created in LiveCycle (xfa format).

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a workaround either, I ended up creating multiple templates with the fields the I need removed in each case. Not the best way to handle it, but it will work!

http://pthok.wordpress.com/2010/12/16/itextsharp-removing-fields-from-pdf-templates/